# How to find the closests points of two numpy arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, distance

I have two numpy arrays: ones is some coordinates (`x`, `y`, `z`) with an id and another one is only some coordinates (`x`, `y`, `z`):

```
cord_id=np.array([[0.,0.,0.,8.],[0.,0.,10.,8.],[0.,0.,20.,8.],[0.,0.,30.,8.],\
                  [2.,1.,0.,9.],[2.,1.,10.,7.],[2.,1.,20.,7.],[2.,1.,30.,7.]])
cord_only=np.array([[0.,0.,.1],[0.,0.,20.1],[2.1,1.,0.],[2.,1.,11.1]])
```

I want to find out each point of `cord_only` is closer to which point of `cord_id` and then add the related id (last column of `cord_id`) to the point. For example, the first point of `cord_only` is closest to first point of `cord_id`, so I add `8.` to it. Second point of `cord_only` is closest to third of `cord_id`, third is closest to fifth and fourth is also closet to sixth point. Finally, I want to get it as:

```
new_arr=np.array([[0.,0.,.1,8.],[0.,0.,20.1,8.],[2.1,1.,0.,9.],[2.,1.,11.1,7.]])
```

I tried the following code but could not find out the closet points:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
cord_id[np.where(np.min(distance.cdist(cord_only, cord_id[:,:-1]),axis=0))]
```

i do appreciate any help in advance to do it in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using np.where(np.min(X)) doesn't give you the correct answer as min returns the minimum value (rather than the index of the minimum value) and where will return all nonzeros. I think what you are looking for is argmin:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
ids = cord_id[np.argmin(distance.cdist(cord_only, cord_id[:,:-1]),axis=1)][:,-1]
new_arr = np.hstack([cord_only,ids.reshape(-1,1)])
```